# jQuery .focus() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The below implementation is for a set of three radio buttons, with the buttons having `display :none` in their CSS paired with labels.

Now I've been trying to add some accessibility options to the page so that you can use the arrow keys to navigate across the radio buttons, changing the focus of the labels on each keypress. But I can't, for the life of me get it to change focus, the focus remains on the initial label that was tabbed to.

I've tried a number of options that I've seen here in regards to timeout and enabling `tabIndex` as I go (want it to act as a group), none have worked.

JS:

```
    $(".radio-type label").keydown(function (e) {
        // On Right Key press
        if (e.which == 39) {

            //Get the list of all buttons and labels
            var parentList = $(".radio-type").children();

            //Get index of currently focussed button
            var indexThis = $(this).index();

            //If not at the end of the list
            if (indexThis < parentList.length) {

                //Get the next in the list and its label
                var next = parentList.get(indexThis + 1);
                var nextLabel = parentList.get(indexThis + 2);

                $(next).change(); //Custom method that changes the selection

                //Remove the tab index from old and assign to nextLabel
                $(this).removeAttr("tabIndex");
                $(nextLabel).attr("tabIndex", "0");

                //Change the focus to the new selected label
                $(nextLabel).focus();
            }
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

**EDIT**: HTML Markup (names modified)

```
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-4 columns radio-type @(!Model.ExtendedFilteringEnabled ? "medium-push-4" : "")">
    <input type="radio" name="tt" id="ttAll" value="@Model.CurrentBlock.TTAll" checked="checked" />
    <label for="ttAll" tabindex="0">All</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tt" id="tt1" value="@Model.CurrentBlock.TT1" />
    <label for="tt1">1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="tt" id="tt2" value="@Model.CurrentBlock.TT2" />
    <label for="tt2">2</label>
</div>
```

Updated Cory's jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n99o3upp/10/ (Sorry keep buggering it up...)

Comment: you should show us your html markup :)

Comment: Updated, hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: `var parentList = $(".radio-type").children();` is not returning a list. put the radio buttons in a named DIV and get the list of buttons in the div `var parentList = $("#radio-btns").children();` Also the keydown on the label may be an issue. Is the keydown firing? add an alert() to see http://jsfiddle.net/n99o3upp/

Comment: If you could create a JSFiddle of your code, you'll get helped quickly.

Comment: well if you want to set the focus on a label this wont work since the label element cant receive focus directly only by the means of its input; since you put the for tag correctly it should be simply enough to focus the related control

Comment: You can't focus controls with CSS display:none though can you?

Comment: Instead of display none, use `left:-9999px; position:relative;`. Then you will still have access to the focus event and the input will be hidden still.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle with a few things:

- Changed markup for easier DOM traversal. Labels now contain their inputs.
- Changed events to fire off inputs rather than labels
- Changed your set method to use `prop` instead of `attr` as this will set the actual value in the DOM
- Made the comparison on the `if` statement look for an index smaller that the `length -1` as index is 0 based and length is 1 based.
- Made the CSS hide the input by positioning rather than display. I commented this out in the fiddle so that you can see the input change
- Added e.preventDefault() to stop the default browser action interfering with your js

The new fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/n99o3upp/16/

However, I am not sure any of this code is necessary, as without it the browser will do the same thing anyway. The right and left key will automatically move the focus to the next input in the group when the DOM is marked up like this.

I think you could remove the `keydown` event  function and just leave the `change` event function and this would do the same thing that you want. You can test it by moving right through the inputs, and then moving back to the left. Both work, but moving right is controlled by your script and moving left is automatic.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Unfortunately I can't implement them. The CSS display:none was a design decision and has to be stuck with hence the events need to fire off the labels because the inputs are hidden.

I only included the right code in this as well not to make it too lengthy, the code to move left is pretty much the same except for which input it takes.

Comment: @mafyou, you can't fire a keydown event off a label. Just to be clear, I am not saying you should have the inputs visible - this was just for the fiddle so you could see them changing. If you uncomment the css in the fiddle you will see that the inputs are hidden just like when using `display:none`. The alternative is to run the keydown off the document, but then it will fire on any keypress, all the time, making your hugely inefficient. Have a look at this new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n99o3upp/17/ - click into the text box, tab to the inputs, and then use your keyboard to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a rough solution that doesn't fix all cases.

I've dropped the requirement of having it navigable by the arrow keys. All the labels have tabindex="0" on them so they can be tabbed through and activated using space or enter. If they want to move back the default Shift+Tab can do that.

Unfortunately, this solution will not work on Chrome as the browser's behaviour won't let you focus on the label if the control is hidden.